# Implement empty element to repeat td in angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, html-table

I have to repeat columns starting from third. Since one cannot put another tab inside a `tr`, what is that `hybrid` element I can use here in this example?

```
    <table>
        <tr>
           <th colspan='2'>Category</th>
           <th ng-repeat='p in ps' colspan='3'>{{p.id}}</th></tr>
        <tr ng-repeat='c in cats'>
            <td>{{c.code}}</td>
            <td>{{c.label}}</td>
         <hybrid ng-repeat='p in ps'>
            <td>{{p.quantity}}</td>
            <td>{{p.cost}}</td>
            <td>{{p.quantity*p.cost}}</td>
         </hybrid>                
        </tr>
    </table>
```

I have unsuccessfully tried something like following

```
   app.directive("hybrid",function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {              
            element[0].outerHTML = element[0].outerHTML;
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);
          }
       }
    });
```

what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I exactly don't know your requirement, but you can use repeated `<span>` inside your `<td>`. I tried something similar in [this fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/hfbp6b92/)

**Update:**

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/e28mhhxd/) with only `<td>` and not using directives. Used * sign in fiddle to separate data

Comment: sorry but It had to be `td` only. I created a replace-me directive to replace inner spans and added the ng-repeat to a td than I replace with its htmls. see my answer

Comment: @Bellash: Again I'd to say, I don't know your exact requirement, but I think there is no need to create such complex directives. might slow your page rendering especially on big table data. Here I fork your [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/e28mhhxd/) and put * to separate data. It can be achieved by simple `<table>`

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem as this.

- I created a `replace-me` directive to replace inner `span`s and
- I added the `ng-repeat` to a `td` than I replace with its htmls

See  [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tresorunikin/knq11osu/)

```
   <table>
   <tr>
        <th colspan='2'>Category</th>
        <th ng-repeat='p in ps' colspan='3'>{{p.id}}</th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat='c in cats'>
      <td>{{c.code}}</td>
       <td>{{c.label}}</td>
      <td colspan='3' ng-repeat='p in ps' data-hybrid>
    <span data-replace-me data-replace-with-tag='td'>{{p.quantity}}</span>
    <span data-replace-me data-replace-with-tag='td'>{{p.cost}}</span>
    <span data-replace-me data-replace-with-tag='td'>{{p.quantity*p.cost}}</span>
      </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

or

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

    myApp.directive("hybrid", function($compile) {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          var el = angular.element(htmls);
          $compile(el.contents())(scope);
          element.replaceWith(el);
        }
      }
    });
    myApp.directive("replaceMe", function($compile) {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          var htmls = element.html(),
            el;
          if (attrs.replaceWithTag) {
            htmls = "<" + (attrs.replaceWithTag) + ">" + element.html() +         "</" + (attrs.replaceWithTag) + ">";
          }
          el = angular.element(htmls);
          $compile(el.contents())(scope);
          element.replaceWith(el);
        }
      }
    });

    myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function MyCtrl($scope) {
      $scope.ps = [{
        id: 2,
        quantity: 3,
        cost: 10
      }, {
        id: 5,
        quantity: 7,
        cost: 20
      }];
      $scope.cats = [{
        code: "mycode",
        label: "mylabel"
      }]
    });
```